# Converting Excel values into double quotation with commas between them

Tags: excel, csv

I have a column of numbers in Excel and I want to convert it into list of numbers with double quotation on each element separated by comma and no space between each number.

Excel has:

```
ID
201
202
203
204
```

I want list of numbers with double quotation and comma in between them without space. Something like:

"201","202","203","204"

Thanks!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Here is one suggestion:

In another column, put something like this `=""""&A1&""","` and copy/drag the formula until the end of your column.

Then Copy and Paste that column into MS Word, and paste special using "Keep Text Only".

Now do a find & replace in MS Word for ^p, and keep the "Replace" field empty (this will put it all on one line). You can then copy that back into Excel or wherever you need it.